# How to preformat a string with placeholders depending on the number of input

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.7, placeholder

I have 2 lists of 3 values (c_0, c_1, c_2) and (b, t_pen, d).

I take the minimum of the multiplication between the values of these lists such as:
c_0 * b, c_1 * t_pen or c_2 * d neglecting 0 multiplications.

Then, I need to output a string representing those calculations such that (str) preformatted_line has the adequate number of placeholders 'min({} ⋅ {})', and (tuple) vars (self.c_0, self.b) the adequate values for the placeholders.

So far, I've come to the following solution (which works):

```
        preformatted_line = 'min({} ⋅ {}'
        vars = (self.c_0, self.b)
        if self.c_1.value:
            preformatted_line += ', {} ⋅ {}'
            vars += (self.c_1, self.t_pen) 
        if self.c_2.value:
            preformatted_line += ', {} ⋅ {}'
            vars += (self.c_2, self.d)
        preformatted_line += ')'
```

I would like to learn if there are better ways to perform the following, alternatives, what I could do if I ever encounter a larger number of input with this problem.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Your way is readable and succinct. Don't see any reason to do any other way. Anyway, you might be looking for [codereview.se]

Comment: If you want to boil it down you could use a list comprehension. If we define `vars = [c_0, c_1, c_2]`, then you can get the preformatted line as `preformatted_line = ', '.join(['{} ⋅ {}' for v in vars if v.value])`

Comment: If you do post on the Code Review Community, please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first.